# Python error: Expected 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (45, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3)

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training a model with X_train is of shape(104, 4) and Y_train is of shape(45, 4)like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(50, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size = 10, epochs = 50,
                verbose = 1, validation_split = 0.3)
```

When I try to fit my data, this is the error thrown:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_91 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (45, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3)

I also tried adding a Flatten layer before the first Dense layer but that results in the following error:

> Input 2 is incompatible with layer flatten_3: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

I am not sure how to fix the dimensions.Can you please help me fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: post full error traceback,also what is the shape of your training data

Comment: Please add more details. Thanks

Comment: What's `Sequential`?  What modeling package are you using.  That's the only useful `tag`

Comment: Why are your labels with that really weird shape? You did not include code that produces those labels.

Comment: X_train is of shape(104, 4) and Y_train is of shape(45, 4)like this: this line is correct 
  ?...

Comment: The error shows that y has shape of (45, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3), which looks very odd. You have not included the code that produces x and y

Comment: I don't want to jump to conclusions, but it seems slightly odd that the number of data points in `X_train` is 104 while that for `y_train` is only 45. Are you sure there isn't supposed to be a one-to-one relationship between each training instance and its label?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the entire script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import SGD

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

df = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data",header=0)

df.columns = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width',"Class"]

df, cl = (df.iloc[:,0:4],df['Class'])

df_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df1 = df_scaler.fit_transform(df)

cl1 = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(cl)

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(df1,cl1,test_size = 0.3)

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 3)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(50,input_dim=x_train.shape[1],activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(40,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(30,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(25,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size = 10, epochs = 50,verbose = 1,validation_split = 0.3)
```

And this is the error that it's giving me:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-4c538cd97d59> in <module>()
      1 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      2                     batch_size = 10, epochs = 50,
----> 3                     verbose = 1, validation_split = 0.3)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_91 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (45, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3)
```

Hope this helps you, I'm following an online course and I can't figure out why the error I'm having.

Thanks